# Чат на php, помогите внедрить Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Здраствуйте, есть вопрос, у меня на одном из сайтов есть рабочий чат на PHP и
с базой данных, но он обновляется только при релоаде страницы, тоесть нету Ajax'a, хочу его внедрить, но не знаю как, с самим ajaxом разобрался, но нету идей как его применить, вставлю php код чата, скажите как реализовать обновление сообщений без релоада, возможно переделать код, возможно отслеживать новое сообщение в БД, и тогда запускать Ajax, не знаю, если напишите код, буду признателен.

```
    <?php
if (isset($_SESSION['loggeduser']) and $_SESSION['loggeduser']['ban status'] <= 0) {
//Берём сообщения с БД
$messages  = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `chat`");
    while ($message = mysqli_fetch_assoc($messages)) {
    //Пока $messages не опустеет, превращаем в строки, и выводим сообщение в отдельном блоке
                $messageId = $message['id'];
                $authorInfo = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '".$message['author_id']."' ");
                $author = mysqli_fetch_assoc($authorInfo);
                                        ?>
                //Пока $authorInfo не опустеет, превращаем в строки, и выводим аву и логин автора сообщения
                <div class="message row" id="<?php echo $message['id']?>">
                <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2 messageLeftPart">
                <!--Аватарка автора сообщения в виде фона блока, остальные стили в файле стилей-->
                <div class="authorAvatar" style="background-image: url(../images/uploaded/avatars/<?php if (empty($author['avatar'])){echo 'default.png';} elseif (!empty($author['avatar'])){echo $author['avatar'];} ?>);"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="messageTextAndLogin col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">
            <!--Выводим логин автора в виде ссылки сразу на его профиль-->
            <h4 class="authorLogin"><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $author['id']?>"><?php echo $author['login'];?></a></h4>
            <!--Выводим время отравки сообщения-->
            <p class="messageTime"><?php echo $message['time']?></p>
            <!--Выводим текст сообщения-->
            <p class="messageText"><?php echo $message['text'];?></p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: в нынешнее время используют вебсокеты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чат конечно же лучше делать на websocket, но если вы говорите что чат уже есть и его нужно усовершенствовать. Тогда могу посоветовать смотреть в сторону ajax long polling, это непрерывная очередь ожидающих запросов.
Вот пример:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function mainLoop(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"handler.php", 
            type:"POST",
            data:{"id":id}, // Предадим id чата.
            cahce:false,
            timeout:30000, // Браузер будет ждать ответ 30 сек, если не получит то цикл перезапустится в error.
            async:true,
            success:function(result){
            $("#response").html(result);
                // Получаем результат.
                setTimeout('mainLoop()',10000);
            },
            error:function(){
                setTimeout('mainLoop()',10000);
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        mainLoop(); // Запускаем непрерывный цикл.
    })
</script>
```

И php обработчик

```
<?php       
set_time_limit(30);
if (isset($_SESSION['loggeduser']) and $_SESSION['loggeduser']['ban status'] <= 0) {
    while(true){ // Делаем вечный цикл.

        $id = $_POST["id"];
        $getMessage=(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE id> '$id' "));
        if (mysql_num_rows($getMessage)) {
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($getMessage)){
                // Готовим сообщение.
                // Echo чтото там...
            }

            flush(); // Очистим буфер
            exit; // Прерываем цикл.
        }

        sleep(2); // Перерыв в 2 секунды.

    }
}
```

На клиенте мы запускаем вечный цикл длинных ajax запросов, клиент делает запрос и ждет 30 сек ответ, если ответ не пришел, он повторяет запрос, если пришел, то мы получаем данные, обновляем их, но запрос все равно повторяется, таким образом мы устанавливаем постоянную связь с сервером. Про ajax long pooling в интернете можно найти много информации и примеров.
А на стороне сервера мы делаем вечный цикл в котором раз 2 секунды пытаемся получить сообщение, если сообщение есть то мы прерываем цикл и отдаем данные. Вместо ID сообщения можно использовать метку времени и доставать сообщение у которых метка времени больше чем метка инициализации ajax запроса.

Comment: Спасибо большое за код, просто в php практика была и уже освоился, а в ajax - не было практики,поэтому только учусь, если в дальнейшем буду делать подобное буду учится использовать эти так званые сокеты

Comment: Только не понимаю Вы написали комментарий 'Передадим id чата', но я не понимаю что это значит, у меня в чате id есть только у сообщений и их авторов

Comment: Ну Id это так, поскольку я не знаю структуру вашего чата. Я просто думал что чат не один для всего сайта, поэтому передавал id. Тут вам нужно получать только обновления, тоесть только новые сообщения, поэтому, я бы посоветовал, передавать метку времени запроса и сообщения с базы доставать только "старше" этой метки.

Comment: Я и собираюсь передавать допустим время отправки сообщения, но как мне это отправить с помощью ajax в поле data?

Comment: В js объявите переменную timestamp и передавайте в ней дату. Или лучше если вы будете инициализировать чат с помощью аякс, то можно при первом обращении передавать пустой timestamp, при этом в обработчике php установить проверку, если timestamp пустой то вернуть все сообщения и метку времени последнего (правда отправлять это уже нужно в формате json) а на клиенте записывать эту метку в timestamp и отдавать обратно, и каждый раз обновлять метку последнего сообщения. Для отправки json `echo json_encode($array)` для получения не стороне клиента `var res = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Ага, ну я так и сделаю, вроде бы с JSON дружу, спасибо за идею

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае это выглядит вот так:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    var form=$(this);
    $.ajax({
        method:"post",
        url:form.attr("action")+"&ajax",
        data:form.serialize(),
        cache:false,
        error:function(){
            //do something
        },
        success:function(result){
            //do something
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

PHP обрабатывает данные из формы и возвращает ответ от сервера обратно в js

Answer (score -1):

Работаю сейчас с чатами, долго вникал.
Итак, если хочешь чат с блекджеком и real-time и есть время писать самому - бери https://socket.io/ или http://socketo.me/ 
Если времени поменьше и нужны всякие cloud functions типа push notifications- твой выбор http://parseplatform.org/ 
Если времени совсем мало, нужен готовый чат с чат-румами и прочими прелестями - бери firebase https://firebase.google.com/ 
По firebase очень много документации, готовых примеров, sdk на всех языках, включая пхп https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ 
Надеюсь, инфа была полезной. 
P.S. Ajax для чатов - далеко не самое лучшее решение